# Which cordova version supports at least android v2.2?

Tags: android, cordova

I need to develop an android app with phonegap to support at least android v2.2.

Which cordova version supports minimum this one?

I cant really find this information anywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Example App of PhoneGap 2.5.0 has minSDK=7 what is 2.1 `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>`

see https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/2.5.0/lib/android/example/AndroidManifest.xml#L62

same is true for Cordova 2.5.0 :) `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`
see https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/test/AndroidManifest.xml#L48

so the latest should still support Android 2.2 ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova 2.6.0 accelerometer does not work in Android 2.2.1 (SDK level 8) on a real device. The watchAcceleration() callbacks are not invoked. Testing on the Android 4.2 emulator confirms my code works - the watchAcceleration() success callback is invoked. However, the emulator has limited (and incorrect) simulation of movement to exercise the accelerometer functionality.